# Environment setup on vscode remote connection

Tags: vscode-remote

When the vscode remote-ssh extension connects to a client (Linux), is there a way to setup the environment?  Our development process requires several environment variables to be setup.  These are normally setup via the shell rc files.

More detail.

I have a task I've setup, when I run this task it fails because the environment is not setup properly.  However, if I open a terminal (bash) and issue the same command, it works as expected.

Any help appreciated.

I've tried passing variables via ssh and that doesn't seem to be supported in our environment.